# Android text String not appearing (getStringExtra)

Tags: android, text, output

I have parsed data and need to save it and some "text" as a String.
This works:

```
    String abb = in.getStringExtra(KEY_PAST) + " in past";
```

But for this String I need the "text" before it, i.e.:

```
    String acc = in.getStringExtra("Go to" + (KEY_PRESENT));
```

The String acc doesn't appear at all, no error messages - System.out.println(acc) doesn't output anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the *key*, not the String. Try this instead:

```
String acc = "Go to " + in.getStringExtra(KEY_PRESENT);
//    Add a space  ^  as well
```

You should also check to see if `in.getStringExtra(KEY_PRESENT)` returns a real value, not just `null` before you use it..

Answer (score 0):

You need to get extra string with `KEY`=`KEY_PRESENT`, but not with `key`="`go to KEY_PRESENT`" so use:

```
String acc = "Go to" + in.getStringExtra(KEY_PRESENT) ;
```

instead of:

```
 String acc = in.getStringExtra("Go to" + (KEY_PRESENT));
```